# Calling two methods Asynchronously in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to call two methods (one is a webservice, other is a method which helps login a user to home page) asynchronously. I dont need them to return any value, as the webservice method is just used for logging and the other has code to authenticate the user and login to home page. I am on asp.NET 2.0

I tried reading many articles who suggested using delagates etc... but i never worked on these. Can any one help me with this. Will appreciate it.

Comment: Don't need you to return a Success or Failure for the Authentication?

Comment: hmm i dont need to return any value, basically the two methods already have the code which will take care of other stuff. I just need to call these methods asynchronoulsy. sorry if i confused you.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to "fire and forget" then you could just queue thread pool work items:

```
WaitCallback firstAction = delegate { webService.LogAccess(); };
WaitCallback secondAction = delegate { user.Login(); }

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(firstAction);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(secondAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need to wait for results you can use the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method like Jon suggested

if you need to pass an argument into your method

```
string msg = "log message";
WaitCallback firstAction = delegate(object args) 
{ 
  string s = ((object[])args)[0]; 
  webService.LogAccess(s); 
};
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(firstAction, new object[] {msg});
```

i generally will setup another method called LogAsync to handle all of the ceremony

```
void LogAsync(string msg)
{
  WaitCallback firstAction = delegate(object args) 
  { 
    string s = ((object[])args)[0]; 
    webService.LogAccess(s); 
  };
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(firstAction, new object[] {msg});
}
```

Comment: If you're about to queue the request anyway, why would you use a weakly typed argument instead of just the captured variable? You must already have the value, after all...

Comment: Jon/ObeseCoder, i tried using the delegate, and it says "Expression Expected". i used something like this in my main method:

WaitCallback firstAction = delegate(AuthenticatePRONET)
WaitCallback secondAction = delegate(LoginUserAfterAuthenticate)

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AuthenticatePRONET)
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LoginUserAfterAuthenticate)

where AuthenticatePRONET, LoginUserAfterAuthenticate are my two methods. Sorry if i am doing anything wrong syntactically, i am totally new to this concept. can you please elaborate...